# Characters not displayed in endElement() of SAX parser

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I have received the xml response from the server in the format below.(response edited)

1. Hello
2. World

Hello and World are present in separate lines within the message tag.
I am able to display Hello World in characters().
But failed to get the same in endElement().

How do I get the content in multiple lines within the same tag in endElement() of SAX parser.

Comment: Your question is confusing, because the server response you show is certainly not XML format. Please show the XML response exactly in the format you receive it.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is correct. `characters()` is where you are supposed to be getting Hello and World, not `endElement()`. End element signals the end of a tag and characters gets everything in between the tag.

If you want to do something in endElements() with `1.Hello 2.World` then why not create a variable up top? For instance.

```
private String message = null;

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
      String qName)
      throws SAXException {

      System.out.println(message); //or whatever you want to do with message

 }

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
throws SAXException {
    if(isMessage){   //isMessage is set when you run startElement and it runs into the <message> block. 
        message = new String(ch, start, length);
        isMessage = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This example is good but you should keep in mind that characters() could be called multiple times for one element; you need to add to message if it already exists